# How to trigger a command only when the for loop is over?

Tags: vb.net, loops, if-statement

I have a for loop with an If condition inside, and I want to trigger a command only when the loop is over and the If condition wasn't triggered.

Comment: Why do people downvote my question without leaving a comment?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say it's because you have mutilated your original question by extending it with another question. That is rather frowned upon on Stack Overflow. If you have another question, you should post another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to keep a flag. Set it to false by default and when the if statement gets executed you set the flag to true.

```
Dim didIfExecute As Boolean = False

For ...
   If ... Then
      didIfExecute = True
   End If
Next

If Not didIfExecute Then
   ...
End If
```

Comment: Is there a better way to do this, like with simplifying truth table or boolean algebra

Comment: @FinnickOdair it depends on what exactly you are doing in the for and if. Right now, you can't get any simpler than that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Return` for it. `Return` immediately exits the function. Here is a example:

```
 Dim a As Byte
 For a = 10 To 20
   Console.WriteLine("value of a: {0}", a)
   If a= "20" Then
      CoolFunction()
      Return
   End If
 Next
 MsgBox("u will never see this msg! maybe if you edit the if condition...")
```

If the If condition got triggered then it will not execute the code which is  under the loop. If the If condition don't get triggered then everything what is under the loop will be executed.

You could also use a `Boolean` for it. This would not "kill" everything that is under the Loop.

```
 Dim a As Byte
 Dim EvenTriggered As Boolean = False
 For a = 10 To 20
   Console.WriteLine("value of a: {0}", a)
   If a= "20" Then
      CoolFunction()
      EventTriggered = True
   End If
 Next
 If EventTriggered = False Then
     MsgBox("u will never see this msg! maybe if you edit the if condition...")
 End IF
```